# Compiling/ running Javascript in Notepad++ [beginner question]

Tags: javascript, notepad++

I am a beginner programmer.  I have a limited knowledge of javascript, but I have only worked in an IDE.  I am currently following Lifehacker's programming series which teaches javascript.
I have downloaded Notepad++ and have completed a program, but I am not sure of the steps to run it.  In the video, the user is able to just send the program to a browser and the code runs from there.

Here is the video for reference:
http://bit.ly/gUsMd3

Thanks!
(note: i am a beginner to both programming and this site so any constructive criticism is welcome)

Comment: Java and Javascript are completely different languages that happen to have resemblant names.

Comment: I think you forgot to link the video ;)

Comment: @Ilya Kogan, @Box9: Here's [part 1](http://lifehacker.com/5736011/learn-how-to-code-part-i-variables-and-basic-data-types). You can see it's clearly JavaScript and I've edited it accordingly (just fixes one typo).

Comment: Oops! here is the video!


        http://bit.ly/gUsMd3     Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Javascript does not need to be compiled, you can put it between `<script>` and `</script>` in a file, save it as something.html and open it in your browser.

Java needs to be compiled, but that is something completely different.

Comment: Oh! So I save it as an HTML even if its javascript?

Comment: WOW! Thanks! You have been a great help.

Comment: Java is to Javascript what car is to carpet :-)

Comment: ? haha I never meant to compare the languages.  I was just stating prior knowlede.  Merjin understood

Comment: "Oh! So I save it as an HTML even if its javascript?"

Only for embedded javascript. You can use an external javascript file saved as .js and include it in the html using <script src="myFile.js"></script>

Answer (score 4):

Just save the sample code to a file, such as "example.html", and then open that file in a browser.

```
<html>
<script>
alert("hi");
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

To run JavaScript with Notepad++,

1. Type your JavaScript code in Notepad++.
   For instance, type the code
   `window.alert("Hello world!");`
   in Notepad++.
2. Now, enclose your code with `<script>` and `</script>` tags.
   The above code now becomes

   `<script>
   window.alert("Hello world!");
   </script>`
3. Save the file with a `.html` extension.
4. Now, click on `Run -> Launch in Chrome`. The JavaScript code will be run in the Chrome browser.
5. If you modify the code, simply save the changes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) in Notepad++. Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to return to Chrome. Press the Refresh button to run the changed code.

Comment: @Toto It gives step-by-step details (for newbies) with inbuilt-commands of Notepad++ to launch the code in a browser

Answer (score 0):

You can also download a console plugin that would allow you to execute java scripts without leaving Notepad++. See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-n4I3XkZT3Q&noredirect=1) for reference:

Comment: This is for Java.   The OP has Javascript in the title.